# When to use each method of launching a subprocess in Ruby

Tags: ruby, performance, coding-style, standards, subprocess

### 1. ``` `` ``` The Backtick

- *defined in [Kernel](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.src/M001408.html)*

#### 1. a) `%x{}` Percent X < alternate syntax for The Backtick

- *defined in parse.y, see [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287503/where-in-the-ruby-language-is-q-w-etc-defined)*

### 2. `system()`

- *[Kernel#system](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.src/M001441.html)*

### 3. `fork()`

- *[Kernel#fork, Process#fork](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.src/M001439.html)*

### 4. `open()`

- **open a pipe**
- *[Kernel#open](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.src/M001399.html)*

#### 4.a. `IO.popen()` < behaves the same as `open()`

- open a pipe
- *[IO#popen](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IO.src/M000880.html)*

#### 4.b. `open("|-")`

- **fork to a pipe**

#### 4.c. `IO.popen("-")` < behaves the same as `open("|-")`

- fork to a pipe
- see [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611752/ruby-io-popen-with-what-happens-under-the-hood)

### 5. `Open3.popen3()`

- `require 'open3'`
- stdlib [Open3](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/open3/rdoc/classes/Open3.html)

### 6. `PTY.spawn()`

- `require 'pty'`
- stdlib [PTY](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/pty/rdoc/classes/PTY.html)

### 7. `Shell.transact()`

- `require 'shell'`
- stdlib [Shell](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/shell/rdoc/classes/Shell.html)

### When should one forsake the trusty back-tick for one of the more complex methods?

**Edit 1.**
Big thanks to [Avdi Grimm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20487/avdi) for his posts describing example usage of each method: [#1](http://devver.wordpress.com/2009/06/30/a-dozen-or-so-ways-to-start-sub-processes-in-ruby-part-1/) (& [gist](http://gist.github.com/137705)); [#2](http://devver.wordpress.com/2009/07/13/a-dozen-or-so-ways-to-start-sub-processes-in-ruby-part-2/) (& [gist](https://gist.github.com/146199)); [#3](http://devver.wordpress.com/2009/10/12/ruby-subprocesses-part_3/).

They are fantastic resources to answer *How*, but are not explicitly composed to answer *when each should be used* or *Why*, and as such IMHO are not complete answers to this question.

Comment: Have a look at this article series: - [A dozen (or so) ways to start sub-processes in Ruby: Part 1](http://devver.wordpress.com/2009/06/30/a-dozen-or-so-ways-to-start-sub-processes-in-ruby-part-1/)
- [A dozen (or so) ways to start sub-processes in Ruby: Part 2](http://devver.wordpress.com/2009/07/13/a-dozen-or-so-ways-to-start-sub-processes-in-ruby-part-2/)
- [A dozen (or so) ways to start sub-processes in Ruby: Part 3](http://devver.wordpress.com/2009/10/12/ruby-subprocesses-part_3/)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

1. use backticks when you want to easily capture the output of a program in a variable.  you probably only want to use this for short-running programs, because this will block.
2. `system` is convenient in two different cases:

   a. You have a long running program and you want the output to print as it runs (e.g. `system("tar zxvf some_big_tarball.tar.gz")`)

   b. `system` can bypass the shell expansion like `exec` (compare the output of `system "echo *"` and `system "echo", "*"`)

   system blocks until the subprocess has exited.
3. `fork` has a couple different use cases as well:

   a. You want to run some ruby code in a separate process (e.g. `fork { .... }`

   b. You want to run a child process (or different program) without blocking progress of your script `fork { exec "bash" }`.

   `fork` is your friend if you want to daemonize your program.
4. `IO.popen` is useful when you need to interact with the standard out and standard in of a program.  Note that it doesn't capture standard err, so you need to redirect that with `2>&1` if you  care about that.
5. `popen3` gives you a separate file descriptor for standard error (for when you need to capture that separately from standard out)
6. `PTY.spawn` is necessary when you want the spawned program to behave like you are running from the terminal.  See the difference of `grep --color=auto pat file` when spawned with `system` vs `PTY.spawn`

Answer (score 50):

Here's a flowchart based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7263556/2063546).  See also, [using `script` to emulate a terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1402389/2063546).

[image]

Comment: `fork` not universally available so one may still require `spawn`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the flowchart above https://stackoverflow.com/a/30463900/1211266, in case somebody wants it as an editable flowchart in markdown (powered by [mermaid](https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/#/)), here it is:

````
```mermaid
flowchart TD

A{{"Do I want to return to my ruby script, ever?"}} -- No --> B(["Use exec()"])
A -- Yes --> C{{"Is it OK to block until the process completes?"}}
C -- Yes --> D{{"Do I need the program's output to be returned?"}}
D -- Yes --> E(["Use backticks `` or %x{}"])
D -- No --> F(["Use system()"])
C -- No --> H{{"Do I need to interact with the output?"}}
H -- Yes --> J{{"Do I want STDERR?"}}
H -- No --> I(["Use fork()"])
J -- Yes --> L{{"Do I want STDERR in its own separate stream?"}}
J -- No --> K(["Use IO.popen()"])
L -- Yes --> M(["Use Open3.popen3()"])
L -- No --> N{{"Use PTY.spawn()"}}

O>"Outputs to STDOUT"] -.- F
P>"You can always emulate a terminal with the BSD utility called script"] -.- H
Q>"Separate child process; good for daemonizing"] -.- I
R>"You can still use 2>&1 to combine STDERR with STDOUT"] -.- K
S>"Emulates a terminal unconditionally"] -.- M

classDef decision fill:#f8fb99;
classDef action fill:#ffaead;
classDef note fill:#ddd,opacity:0.9,font-weight:200;

class A,C,D,H,J,L decision;
class B,E,F,I,K,M,N action;
class O,P,Q,R,S note;
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Also, there is Process.spawn. From the docs:

> This method is similar to Kernel#system but it doesn't wait for the
> command to finish.
>
> The parent process should use Process.wait to collect the termination
> status of its child or use Process.detach to register disinterest in
> their status; otherwise, the operating system may accumulate zombie
> processes.