# Convert a series of jpg into an mov file in Ruby (or using any language)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, video, ffmpeg, converters

I am making a site in Ruby in which I have a series of images, (almost like a powerpoint) and I need to automatically convert those images into one continuous video file (mov, mpeg) that shows each image for 5 seconds or so.  Any one have any clues where to start.

I'm also open to using another language if there are tools to get the job done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could probably use FFmpeg to do this. Here's an example from [the FFmpeg Wiki on the subject](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images):

> ffmpeg -framerate 1/5 -i img%03d.jpg -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p -movflags +faststart out.mp4

What this would do is...

- `-i img%03d.jpg`
  Read input from a series of JPEG files named img001.jpg, img002.jpg and so on
- `-framerate 1/5`
  ...at one frame per five seconds...
- `-c:v libx264`
  ...then turn it into H.264/MPEG-4 AVC...
- `-r 30`
  ...at thirty frames per second...
- `-pix_fmt yuv420p`
  ...with YUV420 pixel format (really, all the FFmpeg flags work here)...
- `-movflags +faststart`
  ...after encoding completes, relocate some data to the beginning of the file so playback can begin before the file is completely downloaded...
- `out.mp4`
  ...and store it into out.mp4.

If you were using this from Ruby you'd likely launch a [subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7212573/). The flags would be similar if you really want a (QuickTime) .mov file instead of H.264 MPEG-4.

Comment: This looks very promising.  Thanks for the info!